# Issue with replacing SOAP End point at run time

Tags: java, web-services, soap, endpoint

We are trying to consume SOAP service (in Java application) which has different end points in prod and pre-prod environments. We generated the client code using wsimport and trying to override the endpoint using binding provider.

Binding provider works fine in pre prod environment ( auto generated code was from pre prod environment wsdl) But when we try to do the testing in production environment , binding provider is not able to override the endpoint.
In production environment it throws " Connection failed when it tries to connect to pre prod".
We learned that binding provider needs access for pre prod wsdl and prod wsdl to override the endpoint. Due to security group restrictions we cant access proprod wsdl from prod.

We also tried to read the end point by calling the service from prod wsdl at run time but port information in wsdl is hardcoded to some IP address and can't be changed and fixing prod wsdl is beyond our control.

Is there any other way to override the endpoint at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main cause for the problem was stubs were having hardcoded QA endpoints. I modified the client stub code, Removed the hardcoded end-points from proxy generated code and Binding provider started working fine.All other solutions were time consuming and environment level changes were required for using gateway services.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use UDDI like solution and keep versioning for your SOAP endpoints or you can use gateway service. This single service will direct the call internally to different services at runtime.

I prefer UDDI because it allows lots of flexibility.
refer: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/admin.1111/e15867/uddi.htm#OSBAG392

Comment: I am analyzing the possible solutions with UDDI and gateway service. In mean time are there any other quick solutions from coding prospective?
Right now our application does not utilize any gateways and UDDI process will also need multiple approvals so just checking if there is something quick.

Comment: you can refer the Axis2 source code and check how it modifies the endpoint before the call. refer this example and check Axis2 src code: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients-xmlbeans.html

Comment: Thanks Amitmah for the suggestion. I got the resolution of this problem. Actually there was a odd Static block and static parameters inside auto generated stub files which was the main problem. We literally changed the  autogenerated code, re-wrote the logic, got read of bunch of constructors and static methods which we are not using. So I found a quicker way by changing the autogenerated files and making sure they don't get replaced in deployments. But still Thanks for all your suggestions it has opened the new ideas which I will keep exploring.